# pyspark dataframe merge multiple json file data in one dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to merge multiple json files data in one dataframe before performing any operation on that dataframe. Lets say I have two files file1.txt , file2.txt which contains data like

file1.txt

```
{"a":1 , "b":"abc", "c":"abc2", "d":"abc3"}
```

file2.txt

```
{"a":1 , "b":"abc", "c":"abc2", "d":"abc3"}
```

So I am reading both the files one by one like this

```
range = ["file1","file2"]
for r in range:
    df = spark.read.json(r)
df.groupby("b","c","d").agg(f.sum(df["a"]))
```

But the dataframe is overriding the first dataframe data and only showing the 2nd dataframe data. How Can I concat these dataframes? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to union dataframes instead of overriding `df` variable. For example:

```
>>> dataframes = map(lambda r: spark.read.json(r), range)
>>> union = reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.unionAll(df2), dataframes)
```

Above code maps all files from `range` array to corresponding dataframes and unions them all.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It is working perfectly fine.